# heroku pg:psql pends and doesn't even display any errors (Windows)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql

So I've created a Heroku app and a database for it. When I use the terminal (Git Bash), commands like `heroku pg:info` work just fine and show that the database exists and is connected to my app. However, when I type `heroku pg:psql` (or `heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL`), it says `--> Connecting to postgresql-reticulated-30033`:

[heroku pg:psql result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ig3nt.png)

And then nothing happens. It doesn't display any errors like "unable to reach database" or anything. I couldn't find a clear solution for this problem, nobody else seems to be having no responses whatsoever. I've seen suggestions like "maybe ports 5000 and 5432 are blocked by a corporate firewall" but I'm not sure where to even go from here.

pls hlp

Answer (score 0):

So I had a bright idea to try this in regular Windows Command Prompt and it worked right away. So it solves my problem for now, though I still don't know why it wouldn't work in Git Bash.